# Why do the changes I made in camera raw look bad when I open the image in pse?

Tags: post-processing, raw, photoshop-elements

So I open my raw file in Adobe camera raw, edit and get it just right, then I click open image to make some final adjustments in pse and my image appears in pse completely over edited! What's happening?
I'm finding that I have to under edit in camera raw and then finish in pse to allow for the complete difference in the output of the file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello Julie, welcome to Photo.SE . Are they using the same process version (which version of Adobe camera Raw / pse) ? Are you using XMP sidecar files ? Does it look like your edit is being applied twice ?

Comment: I'd check the colour management settings of PSE, but i can't be more specific since i only have PS.

Comment: Could you provide a link to a couple of examples? The same image exported directly from ACR and exported from PSE without any further changes? What color space is selected in your settings for each application? Are they the same?

Comment: Hi I was using no colour management settings in pse13 but I've just changed that to optimise for computer screens. I didn't realise you can change colour profiles in ACR just camera profiles?